# attributeChangedCallback() always called twice ending up with multiple event listeners

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

Playing around with custom elements, I'm trying to get a click event fired depending on custom element attribute's value. But using the `attributeChangedCallback()` method (along with the `connectedCallback()` method) I'm ending up with multiple event listeners.

```js
class HelloWorld extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['attribute1', 'attribute2'];
  }

  get attribute1() {
    return this.getAttribute('attribute1');
  }
  set attribute1(val) {
    if (val) {
      this.setAttribute('attribute1', val);
    } else {
      this.removeAttribute('attribute1');
    }
  }

  get attribute2() {
    return this.getAttribute('attribute2');
  }
  set attribute2(val) {
    if (val) {
      this.setAttribute('attribute2', val);
    } else {
      this.removeAttribute('attribute2');
    }
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.textContent = 'Hello World';
    update(this);
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    update(this);
  }
}
customElements.define('hello-world', HelloWorld);

function update(el) {
  if (el.attribute1 === 'foo') {
    el.addEventListener('click', e => {
      el.textContent = (el.textContent.indexOf(' (') != -1 ? el.textContent.substring(0, el.textContent.indexOf(' (')) : el.textContent) + ' (clicked ' + (el.textContent.match(/\d+/) ? parseInt(el.textContent.match(/-?\d+/)[0]) + 1 : 1) + ' times)';
    });
  } else if (el.attribute1 === 'bar') {
    el.addEventListener('click', e => {
      el.textContent = (el.textContent.indexOf(' (') != -1 ? el.textContent.substring(0, el.textContent.indexOf(' (')) : el.textContent) + ' (clicked ' + (el.textContent.match(/\d+/) ? parseInt(el.textContent.match(/-?\d+/)[0]) - 1 : 1) + ' times)';
    });
  }
}
```

```css
hello-world {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<hello-world attribute1="foo" attribute2=""></hello-world>
```

Why is the `attributeChangedCallback()` method always called twice and therefore adds two event listeners? How to avoid this? What would be best practice?

Comment: Pretty certain it's called once for `attribute1` and once for `attribute2`. Did you try logging `name`, `oldValue` and `newValue`?

Comment: You're right. I think I did. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called `attributeChangedCallback`, so fires on every **single** attribute change, including init when the element is added to the DOM

Attach listeners in the `connectedCallback`, but that **can** run again if you move the element in the DOM, so you have to remove them in the `disconnectedCallback`

Easier might be to use an *inline* EventHandler, there can only be one on an element.

```js
customElements.define('hello-world', class extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['attribute1', 'attribute2'];
  }
  get attribute1() {
    return this.getAttribute('attribute1');
  }
  set attribute1(val) {
    this.toggleAttribute('attribute1', val);
  }
  get attribute2() {
    return this.getAttribute('attribute2');
  }
  set attribute2(val) {
    this.toggleAttribute('attribute2', val);
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    this.count = 0;
    this.innerHTML = `Hello World clicked: <span>${this.count}</span> times`;
    this.onclick = (evt) => {
      this.count++;
      this.querySelector("span").innerHTML = this.count;
    }
  }
  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    console.log("attributeChangedCallback", name, oldValue, newValue);
  }
});
```

```css
hello-world {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<hello-world attribute1="foo" attribute2=""></hello-world>
```

```
constructor() {
  super()
}
```

is not required, a non existing `constructor` will execute the `constructor` from its parent.. which is what `super()` does.

If you want to prevent multiple listeners you could try a method:

```
addListeners(){
  .. add your listeners

  this.addListeners = () => {}; // overload; Don't run its original code again
}
```

Also note Listeners you add on the Element (or its contents) are automaticall *garbage collected*/*removed* when the element is removed from the DOM.
Any Listeners you add on other DOM elements (eg. document) you have to remove yourself in the `disconnectedCallback`